# Operator overloading for primitive types in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators

In C++, if you've got a class Foo, and you want users of Foo to be able to write:

```
Foo x;
x += 3;
```

, you can simply make a member function of Foo, `Foo& operator+=(int rhs)`.  If you want to be able to write:

```
Foo x;
int y = 3;
y += x;
```

, you cannot accomplish this by writing a member function of Foo, instead one has to write an external function, which usually must be declared as a friend of Foo.

How hard would it be for a future version of C++ to say that this **can be** written with a Foo member function `int& operator+=(int &lhs, Reversed)`, where Reversed was some empty class whose sole purpose was to distinguish the two versions of the operator?

If this were done, it could probably eliminate the vast majority of the uses of the `friend` keyword in new code.

Comment: I don't think it's an option in near future. It feels like some random idea, you would have to break rules for member `@=` operators. I would rathed add imaginary keyword that says that `lhs` is now `rhs`, but the question is "Why?". The current syntax works well and there is no point. Well, wait 10 years and see.

Comment: @BlackMoses you can define those operators already. its not a random idea. `operatorXxx`-methods can be defined outside of a class even for primitive types

Comment: @msrd0 Inside class body without declaring friendship? EDIT: ok, misread in and out.

Comment: @BlackMoses I though that I might have written "can be defined outside of a class" - but anyway, reading is hard

Comment: @msrd0 Well, still you have to declare them somehow, and you can't do that for primitive types as some `Foo` method without friendship, and that was the point.

Comment: @BlackMoses primitive types don't need friendship, and if `Foo` would declare it's value as public (I can't find class definition) it would be possible. And even if it's declared private, think of `int& operator+=(int &lhs, Foo &rhs) { Foo f = rhs + lhs; return f; }` - here you can define all the needed operators in `Foo` (the compiler will optimize this anyway, so it won't make much difference later on)

Comment: @msrd0 That's not the point of the whole question. I know, and OP knows, that you can have external declaration of such operator, but the core word is **inside** class body. And that can't be done (without `friend`-ship as I repeat all this time). And it isn't about friendship to `lhs`, but to the `operator @=`.

Comment: @BlackMoses As I am repeating all the time there is no problem to do this without the `friend` declaration in many different ways - but I agree that you need to write it outside of the class.

Answer (score 2):

You can in fact define such an operator, because you are free to overload `+=` for built-in types:

```
int& operator+=(int &lhs, Foo &rhs) {
  lhs += rhs.somefield;
  return lhs;
}
```

On the other hand, instead of writing overloaded functions for all possible operators, you can also provide a function that will allow implicit casts of `class Foo` to `int`:

```
class Foo {
  ... somefield;

  operator int() {
    return (int)somefield;
  }
};
```

Comment: This does not compile: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc94493995f99088. It was about not using friend keyword and declare the operator inside class body. P.S. Thanks for correction G. Sliepen :)

Comment: @BlackMoses Move the operator outside of the class and it will compile without any problems